# How would you parse a log4net message into it's component parts

Tags: c#, regex, log4net

Given the below log4net message, how would you parse it, using c#, to split it into it's component part's?

2012-01-23 22:00:30,001 [18] ERROR DEFAULT [(null)]  [(null)] - Test generated error
System.Exception: Test Exception
   at blah.Dashboard.Web.__Admin.GenerateError.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Dashboard\src\blah.Dashboard.Web__Admin\GenerateError.aspx.cs:line 12

Comment: Playing with putting delimiters in my log4net format string in so i can just do a split. Wondering it a different/better way?

Comment: I think Mitch Wheat is asking why you want to split the messages. What do you want to do after you split the log messages?

Comment: It's ok I got it working. The reason for doing it was I have written a monitoring dashboard, and all our websites will send log4net errors using the udp appender to a central service. Was going to then split it up so I can query against it using sql. I know there are tools that do this..but it was more of a technical exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Read the logfile using [streamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and then streamReader.ReadToEnd() to get entire content in a string. Then use string.Indexof method to get index of different component and retrieve their values.